# Cauchy Sequence and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cauchy-sequences

> Suppose $f$ is a uniformly continuous mapping of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$. If {$x_n$} is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, then {$f(x_n)$} is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$.
>
> Give an example to show that this statement is not true if $f$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous.

I was thinking maybe something like $\frac{x}{n}$? Not really sure if I understand this problem correctly. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: For the first part, use what it means for a sequence to be Cauchy and a function to be uniformly continuous. For the second, you need to find metric spaces $X,Y$, a continuous function $f:X\to Y$, and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not Cauchy in $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$  This is clearly cauchy, as it converges.  Now consider $f: \mathbb{R/\{0\}} \to \mathbb{R/\{0\}}$, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$